# Python root logger messages not being logged via handler configured with fileConfig

Tags: python, python-2.7, logging, configuration-files

**The Problem:**

Given a logging config and a logger that employs that config, I see log messages from the script in which the log handler is configured, but not from the root logger, to which the same handler is assigned.

**Details:**

(Using Python 2.7)

I have a module `my_mod` which instantiates a logger. `my_mod` has a function `my_command` which logs some messages using that logger. `my_mod` exists inside of a library `my_lib`, so I don't want to configure the logger with any handlers; as recommended, I want to leave the log handling to the developer using `my_mod`. `my_mod` looks like:

```
import logging

LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def my_command():
    LOGGER.debug("This is a log message from module.py")
    print "This is a print statement from module.py"
```

I also have a python script `my_script.py`, which uses `my_mod.my_command`. `my_script.py` instantiates a logger, and in this case I do have handlers and formatters configured. `my_script.py` configures handlers and formatters using `fileConfig` and a config file that lives alongside `my_script.py`:

```
import os
import logging
import logging.config
from my_mod.module import my_command

logging.config.fileConfig('{0}/logging.cfg'.format(
    os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))))
LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

LOGGER.debug("This is a log message from script.py")
my_command()
```

From what I can tell, my config file appears to be set up correctly...

```
[loggers]
keys=root,script

[handlers]
keys=consoleHandler

[formatters]
keys=simpleFormatter

[logger_root]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler

[logger_script]
level=DEBUG
handlers=consoleHandler
qualname=script
propagate=0

[handler_consoleHandler]
class=StreamHandler
level=DEBUG
formatter=simpleFormatter
args=(sys.stdout,)

[formatter_simpleFormatter]
format=%(asctime)s [%(levelname)s] %(name)s: %(message)s
datefmt=
```

...but when I run `my_script.py` I get only the log line from `my_script.py`, and not the one from `my_mod.my_command`. I know that `my_command` is working, though, because the print statement in `my_command` after the debug log statement successfully prints to the console:

```
20:27 $ python script.py 
2015-06-15 20:27:54,488 [DEBUG] __main__: This is a log message from script.py
This is a print statement from module.py
```

What am I doing wrong?

NOTE: The example shows using debug, but even when I keep logging.cfg specifying `level=DEBUG` (I also tried `level=NOTSET`) for root logger and call `LOGGER.info(message)` in `my_command`, nothing is logged to the console.

Comment: It should not make a difference (it does not here), but have you tried setting up the logger configuration before you import your module?

Comment: That's exactly the problem. Thanks! If you post it as an answer, I will mark it as such.

Comment: Note updated answer, this behaviour is actually documented (albeit I don't know the reason why it is the way it is).

Comment: Got it. Thanks. I've opted to set disable_existing_loggers=False.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A potential problem is that you are importing the module before you set up the logger configuration. That way, the module requests a logger before the logging is setup.

Looking a [`fileConfig()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.config.html#logging.config.fileConfig)'s documentation, the reason subsequent logging to the pre-obtained loggers fails is the default value for its `disable_existing_loggers` argument:

```
logging.config.fileConfig(fname, defaults=None, disable_existing_loggers=True)
```

If you change your code to

```
logging.config.fileConfig(
    '{0}/logging.cfg'.format(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))),
    disable_existing_loggers=False
)
```

the problem should go away.

Note that existing loggers are only disabled when they are not explicitly named in the configuration file. For example:

```
import logging
import logging.config

lFooBefore = logging.getLogger('foo')
lScriptBefore = logging.getLogger('script')
logging.config.fileConfig('logger.ini')

lFooBefore.debug('Does not log')
lScriptBefore.debug('Does log')
logging.getLogger('foo').debug('Does also not log')
logging.getLogger('bar').debug('Does log')
```

No idea why the default value for `disable_existing_loggers` is the way it is ...

Comment: Great explanation! Thx!

Comment: Note that `disable_existing_loggers` can also be used in dictConfig, in the dictionary provided itself for the same effect.